# Azure CosmosDB: Improve Bulk insertion performance

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Azure Cosmos DB SDK(3.0) for CRUD operations. When i am trying to insert 8,000-10,000 records at the same time, then its taking almost 3-4 mins.

Here is my code:

```
  public async Task<ResultDto> HandleAsync(EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommand command, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.Info("Started EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommand ", nameof(EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommand));
            
            if (command.UiNotifications.Any())
            {
                await AddSubscription(command, SubscriptionAction.UiNotification, command.UiNotifications);
                logger.Info("Added UI notification subscriptions");
            }
            if (command.EmailNotifications.Any())
            {
                await AddSubscription(command, SubscriptionAction.Email, command.EmailNotifications);
                logger.Info("Added Email notification subscriptions");
            }

            return new ResultDto { ResultType = ResultType.Success, Message = $"User {command.UserId} SubscriptionStatus" };
        }

        
        private async Task AddSubscription(EnableOrDisableSubscriptionCommand command, SubscriptionAction subscriptionAction, IList<int> notificationCategoryTypes)
        {
            foreach (var notificationCategory in notificationCategoryTypes)
            {
                var notificationTypes = Utility.GetNotificationTypes((NotificationCategoryType)notificationCategory);

                foreach (var notificationType in notificationTypes)
                {
                    foreach (var payerAccountSubscriptions in command.Subscriptions)
                    {
                        if (payerAccountSubscriptions.AccountNumbers?.Any() ?? false)
                        {
                            foreach (var accountNumber in payerAccountSubscriptions.AccountNumbers.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)))
                            {
                                await _repository.Create(subscriptionAction, notificationType,
                                     payerAccountSubscriptions.ColCoId, payerAccountSubscriptions.PayerNumber, accountNumber, command.UserRole,
                                     command.UserId);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await _repository.Create(subscriptionAction, notificationType,
                                payerAccountSubscriptions.ColCoId, payerAccountSubscriptions.PayerNumber, null, command.UserRole,
                                command.UserId);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Subscription Repository Create Method:

```
 public async Task Create(SubscriptionAction subscriptionAction, NotificationType notificationType,
            int colCoId, string payerNumber, string accountNumber, UserRole userRole, string userId, string cardId = null)
        {
            var eventType = Utility.GetEventType(notificationType);

            var subscriptionBase = new Subscription
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                IsActive = true,
                Action = subscriptionAction,
                ActionDesc = subscriptionAction.ToString(),
                Version = (int)SubscriptionVersion.V2,
                NotificationType = notificationType,
                NotificationTypeDesc = notificationType.ToString(),
                EventType = eventType,
                EventTypeDesc = eventType.ToString(),
                ColCoId = colCoId,
                PayerNumber = payerNumber,
                AccountNumber = accountNumber,
                CardId = cardId,
                DistributionGroups = new List<string> { userRole.ToString() },
                DistributionUserIds = new List<string> { userId }
            };
            await CreateItemAsync(subscriptionBase);
        }
```

Generic Repository:

```
 public async Task<ItemResponse<T>> CreateItemAsync(T item)
        {
            return await _container.CreateItemAsync<T>(item);
        }
```

Due to this issue, My Http Trigger Azure Function returning System.OutOfMemoryException.

How Can I improve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can improve this by setting `AllowBulkExecution = true` in the client and adding each insert operation to a task to execute.

You can learn more and see an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-migrate-from-bulk-executor-library)

Edit: (this is too long to add as comment)
How much RU/s you need depends on a number of factors including how fast you want to ingest the data. I would measure the cost of inserting one of these items and then dividing your provisioned throughput by the amount to insert one item. The result should be the number of items you can insert per second (assuming you are doing nothing else). If you have one item that costs 10 RU/s to insert and you have 3000 RU/s provisioned you can ingest 300 items per second. For 10,000 total items / 300 per second = 33 seconds.

So if this is taking 3-4 minutes then there is something else wrong with your code. I would go back and read the article I posted above because I do not see you implementing the pattern we suggest, specifically putting each operation on a List object and then call `await Task.WhenAll(this.Tasks);`

Another issue I see is you are not specifying the partition key in your InsertItemsAsync() call. This will write everything to a single null partition and will eventually stop accepting any new writes once it reaches 20GB in size.

Comment: and how Can I improve the retrieve operation?

Comment: You may just need to provision more throughput. General rule of thumb is 1KB or less insert costs around ~8 RU. You'll need to do the math to sort out the payload size for each item, the number of them and the amount of time.

Comment: Read operations are fastest when done as point reads (i.e. ReadItemAsync() ). Queries are more expensive and also should try to avoid cross-partition queries for highest read throughput.

Comment: I have set 3000 Throughput  value, still i m getting "Response status code does not indicate success: TooManyRequests (429); Substatus: 3200; ActivityId: ; Reason: ();"

Comment: How much Throughput value required to insert/delete 10-12k item in a bulk? when each item having size at around 1.3kb

Comment: Adding response here to original answer.